# Best way to share data with a producer coroutine loop from the python websockets package?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, coroutine

I want to set up a websocket server in python (using this [websocket library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)) to send data that is generated through a "produce_msg" function. This function does some intense calculations, produces a message and should trigger the sending via websockets.

What is the best way to share the data with the producer coroutine loop and trigger the sending?

I think calling the "produce_msg" function inside the producer coroutine is possible. But can I also call a send function from inside the "producer_msg function? I want to use a websocket class to provide the send functionality to users of this class.

Browser-based example with producer coroutine loop from [websocket library website](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def producer_handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        message = await produce_msg()
        await websocket.send(message)

start_server = websockets.serve(producer_handler, "127.0.0.1", 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

**Update**

I managed to build a version that works using a callback function. In my example I use produce_msg() as callback function.

Till now I did not manage to build a version in which the Websocket class has a send_msg() function that can be called to send a message (instead of a callback function).

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import datetime
import random
import time


class Websocket:
    def __init__(self, callback, ip="127.0.0.1", port=5678):
        self.callback = callback
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

        self.start()

    def start(self):
        start_server = websockets.serve(self.handler, self.ip, self.port)

        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()


    async def handler(self, websocket, path):
        while True:
            msg = self.callback()
            await websocket.send(msg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def produce_msg():
        time.sleep(2.4)
        return datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"

    ws = Websocket(produce_msg)
```

Comment: Do you have a concrete problem with this approach? You should be able to call the `send` function from anywhere, so long as the function is async (so you can await it) and you propagate the `websocket` object.

Comment: Hi @user4815162342, thank you for your quick response. I appended some code in my question. There is my solution in which the Websocket class gets a callback function which can produce the messages that are sent. I tried to do it the other way around. I want to import the Websocket class and call a send function to send away messages. But the event loop is blocking and I did not manage to get it running using threads. I hope you understand what I am trying to archive :)

Comment: Your intention is valid, but the implementation is unclear. Your `produce_msg` is not async, but you await it. `produce_msg` should be defined with `async def` and use `await asyncio.sleep(2.4)` instead of `time.sleep(2.4)`. Have you tried that? What does `produce_msg` **do** in your actual use case? Why are you referring to threads (asyncio is single-threaded)?

Comment: In my actual use case `produce_msg` grabs an image from a camera, runs an object detection inference on it and returns the image + detection results. I think I am a bit confused about the concept of asyncio and how to work with it. I thought I can just create an object `ws` from a websocket class inside my object detection code and actively call something like 'ws.send(msg)' whereby `msg` contains the image + detection results...

Comment: If `produce_msg` uses blocking calls (those that take more than a tiny fraction of a second to complete), you should call it through [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). I.e. you should replace `msg = self.callback()` with `msg = await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, callback)`. That way the `produce_msg` will be executed off-thread and the event loop will not be blocked if it takes a while to complete.